# SoftLayer Objectstore returns Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: https://ams01.objectstorage.service.networklayer.com

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure, object-storage

We are experiencing HTTP 503 (and sometimes 408) errors when we are closing an HTTP UrlConnection to object store. We open and write to the OutputStream and when we close the stream we receive a 503 error.

Where is the "503 Service Unavailable" documented and what happens for this event? Does any cleanup occur? This is happening intermittently.

SoftLayer support suggested I inquire here

Answer (score 0):

If you see specific problems like 503 Service Unavailable, double-check the port values to ensure they match the value in etc/swift/auth-server.conf. When adding a new account/user, the auth server calls out to the proxy server based on the default_cluster_url config file value and it should match the bind_port value. You also have to configure the port for the proxy-server.conf under the [filter:auth] section, which defaults to 11000.